# Dart HttpServer HttpResponse redirect

Tags: javascript, dart, redirect, httpserver

I am using `dart:io`'s HttpServer to implement a web server and I am trying to redirect to a page after using JavaScript to send a DELETE request. Below is a minimal example of what I am trying to do but I cannot get it to work correctly. Currently the below sucessfully returns the home page when I visit `localhost:8000`, it also successfully returns the form button at GET /thing. When I click the delete button, a request is successfully sent to DELETE /thing and a 302 status code is returned. Then a request is made to /deleted as expected but the method is DELETE, and the string "deleted thing, delete method" is returned but not rendered. Firstly I would like to know how to make sure the redirect is using GET not DELETE (i.e. it should be GET /deleted), then I would like to know how to make sure "get deleted" is rendered (assuming solving the former doesn't also fix this). I am not sure whether the problem is in the Dart code or Javascript. The Dart `.redirect()` method doesn't provide a way to change the method, and as far as I can tell Javascript's `fetch()` doesn't either so I have no idea how to make sure the redirect uses GET not DELETE.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  HttpServer server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 8000);

  // assert(app.server != null);
  await for (HttpRequest request in server) {
    String path = request.uri.path;
    String method = request.method;

    if (path == "/" && method == "GET") {
      print("get home");
      request.response.write('home page');
      await request.response.close();
    }
    if (path == "/" && method == 'DELETE') {
      print("delete home");
      request.response.write('home page, with delete method');
      await request.response.close();
    }
    if (path == "/thing" && method == "GET") {
      print("get thing");
      request.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.html;
      request.response.write(
          """<form action="/thing"><input type="submit" value="delete"></form>
            <script>
              const form = document.querySelector("form");
              form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
                event.preventDefault();
                fetch("/thing", { method: "DELETE", redirect: 'follow'}).then(response => 
                alert("deleted thing"));
              });
            </script>""");
    }
    if (path == "/thing" && method == "DELETE") {
      print("delete thing");
      await request.response.redirect(Uri(
          scheme: request.requestedUri.scheme,
          host: request.requestedUri.host,
          port: request.requestedUri.port,
          path: "/deleted"));
    }
    if (path == "/deleted" && method == "GET") {
      print("get deleted");
      request.response.write('deleted thing');
      await request.response.close();
    }
    await request.response.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 303 instead of 302 will ensure the redirect is a GET request instead of a DELETE request, however it turns out it is not possible to make a HTTP request from javascript that redirects because of https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/763.